# How to write multiple SQL query statement and PL/SQL statement inside one PL/SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In 1 PL/SQL block have to use multiple `SELECT` query and one block statement. In this block statement we have to take counts before `insert` query and once `insert` statement run then after have to take its after_counts of the id value that mentioned below.

```
set heading off
set colsep '|'
set feedback off
set sqlformat csv
set trimspool on
spool output.txt
declare
 ln_rec tab1%rowtype;
 lv varchar(20);
 sid tab.id%type;
 b_cnts number;
 a_cnts number;
 type sh_id is varray(10) of tab.col1%type;
 id sh_id := sh_id(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19);
begin
 select a.id, count(b.sub_id) into sid, b_cnts as "before_counts" from tab a, tab1 b;

 for i in (select distinct b.sub_id from tab a, tab1 b where a.id in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19))
 loop
  select * into ln_rec from tab1 where sub_id = i.sub_id;

  insert into new_tab values(id, i.sub_id, lv);
  commit;
 end loop;

 select a.id, count(b.sub_id) into sid, a_cnts as "after_counts" from tab a, tab b;
end;
spool off
```

But when i execute it then got error because of above `SET system variable summary` and in the `insert` statement due to `id`. I want output in the csv format or output format like where 3 columns should be generated as id, before_counts, after_counts & its proper value. Like this:-

```
<id>   <before_counts>    <after_counts>   -- This heading should not appear because above used heading off
1       135                138
3       246                250
5       298                302
7       389                399
.........
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: In PL/SQL you need to use `SELECT .... INTO .... FROM ....` for `SELECT` statements. You have a lot of legacy comma joins with no join conditions that are acting as `CROSS JOIN`s. The `lv` variable is never populated. The `id` variable is a PL/SQL defined `VARRAY` if you want to insert it into a table then it probably needs to be declared globally in an SQL scope rather than a PL/SQL scope and I'm not sure that that is actually your intended behaviour to insert an entire array into the table. Do you really want to `COMMIT` every iteration of the loop? You don't use the `ln_rec` values.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for the sample data and an (English, not code) description of your expected behaviour as it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, you are reading the counts from the (`CROSS JOIN` of the) `tab` and `tab1` tables and inserting into the `new_tab` table. How do you expect the count in `tab`/`tab1` to change when you aren't modifying those tables?

Comment: @MT0 Question has been edited. `lv` variable used in `new_tab` to `insert` the records. In background one  stored procedure is running which i didn't mention here. Once this Stored proc run then after the table got updated.

Comment: The `lv` variable is never populated so its values will always be `NULL`. If you have stored procedures you are using then please [edit] your question to include **ALL** the relevant code because we can't answer a question with half the information.

Comment: Another issue, when you specify an alias for a column, you put the 'as ...' after the column name, not after the var you have in the 'into' clause. And if you want some output from PL/SQL, you need to use dbms_output.put_line. And when you have 'count...', you need a group by the other columns (i.e. a.id in your case).

Comment: I suggest you start with SQL. First re-write all your queries with proper joins. See that you have cross joins where you probably want inner or outer joins. Then take your first query. Look at it. Understand why it is invalid. Correct it. Then look at your cursor query. It makes no sense. Why cross join a table and not use it in the result? Correct it. Only when you have the queries straight, start to use them inside PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```sql
DECLARE
 type sh_id is varray(10) of tab.col1%type;

 a_cnts number;
 b_cnts number;
 lv     varchar2(20) := NULL; -- This is never modified in your code.
 ids    sh_id := sh_id(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. ids.COUNT LOOP
    SELECT count(b.sub_id)
    INTO   b_cnts
    FROM   tab a
           INNER JOIN tab1 b
           ON ( <some join conditions> ) -- you need to specify the join
    WHERE  a.id = ids(i);

    INSERT INTO new_tab
    SELECT DISTINCT
           ids(i),
           b.sub_id,
           lv
    FROM   tab a
           INNER JOIN tab1 b
           ON ( <some join conditions> ) -- you need to specify the join
    WHERE  a.id = ids(i);

    -- Assuming you have a trigger to populate tab or tab1 from new_tab then
    a_cnts := b_cnts + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    -- Otherwise:
    SELECT count(b.sub_id)
    INTO   a_cnts
    FROM   tab a
           INNER JOIN tab1 b
           ON ( <some join conditions> ) -- you need to specify the join
    WHERE  a.id = ids(i);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ids(i) || CHR(9) || b_cnts || CHR(9) || a_cnts );
  END LOOP;

  -- Commit outside the loop
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```